# What are $E^+,C^+$ and the p-part of the quotient $E^+/C^+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-groups, cyclotomic-fields

In L.Washington Introduction to Cyclotomic fields, Chap 8, p 146 we read:

> Finding nontrivial examples appears to be difficult since $h_n^+=1$
>   for small $n$ and for large $n$ the calculations required to determine $E^+$ or the class group are extremely lengthy. The next question is whether or not the $p$-part of $E^+/C^+$ is isomorphic to the $p$-Sylow subgroup of the class group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^m})$.

I guess in this context, $E^+$ and $C^+$ denote respectively the full unit group and the cyclotomic units group of the maximal real part of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p^m})$ and $C^+$.

But what is the $p$-part of $E^+/C^+$? I couldn't find a definition in the book or elsewhere. Is it $p$-subgroup of $E^+/C^+$?

Thank you.

### Edit

[image]

Comment: It's surely the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $E^+/C^+$.

Comment: What you wrote suggests $E^+=O_{\Bbb{R}\cap \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^m})}^\times=\Bbb{Z}[\cos(2\pi /p^m)]^\times$ and $C^+$ is the torsion which makes no sense. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Thank you!
@reuns, I found this definition in Washington's book: Let $K$ be a CM-field and let $E$ be its unit group. Let $E^+$ be the unit group of $K^+$ so I guess what I wrote about $E^+$ makes sense? For $C^+$, could you please explain why it is the torsion and why it doesn't make sense? I added some context in the question